# Flink log files on Emr

Tags: apache-flink, emr

I have my Flink jar running in Emr. I have logback.xml set to /mnt/var/flink.log as the path for it when it is running on Emr. I can only see the the logs which are formed by the Emr while running the jar but not mine. Please suggest me a way how to get the logs which i have defined in the programs which is running as Flink jar in Emr. I am unable to find proper solution to it.  My logback.xml looks like:

```
<configuration>
<logger name="org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.JobGraph" level="INFO" additivity="false">
<appender-ref ref="file" />
</logger>
    <appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>/mnt/var/log/flink.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{60} %X{sourceThread} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="file"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be related to [FLINK-7990](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7990), as per [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47009503/logback-not-working-in-flink). But note that you have to put the `logback.xml` file Flink's `conf` directory on the system from where you launch Flink. Side note - it's very helpful if you include the version of Flink when asking questions, as it's a fast-moving target.